# Scrapy request.meta is updated incorrectly

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to log crawled paths to the `meta` attribute:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["www.iana.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.iana.org/']
    request_path_css = dict(
        main_menu = r'#home-panel-domains > h2',
        domain_names = r'#main_right > p',
    )

    def links(self, response, restrict_css=None):
        lex = LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains=self.allowed_domains,
            restrict_css=restrict_css)
        return lex.extract_links(response)

    def requests(self, response, css, cb, append=True):
        links = [link for link in self.links(response, css)]
        for link in links:
            request = scrapy.Request(
                url=link.url,
                callback=cb)
            if append:
                request.meta['req_path'] = response.meta['req_path']
                request.meta['req_path'].append(dict(txt=link.text, url=link.url))
            else:
                request.meta['req_path'] = [dict(txt=link.text, url=link.url)]
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        #self.logger.warn('## Request path: %s', response.meta['req_path'])
        css = self.request_path_css['main_menu']
        return self.requests(response, css, self.domain_names, False)

    def domain_names(self, response):
        #self.logger.warn('## Request path: %s', response.meta['req_path'])
        css = self.request_path_css['domain_names']
        return self.requests(response, css, self.domain_names_parser)

    def domain_names_parser(self, response):
        self.logger.warn('## Request path: %s', response.meta['req_path'])
```

Output:

```
$ scrapy crawl -L WARN example
2017-02-13 11:06:37 [example] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
2017-02-13 11:06:37 [example] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
2017-02-13 11:06:37 [example] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
2017-02-13 11:06:37 [example] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
2017-02-13 11:06:37 [example] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
2017-02-13 11:06:38 [example] WARNING: ## Request path: [{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
```

This is not what I expected, as I would like to have just the last url in `response.meta['req_path'][1]`, however *all urls from the last page* somehow find their way to the list.

In other words, the expected output is such as:

```
[{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/root', 'txt': 'The DNS Root Zone'}]
[{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/int', 'txt': '.INT'}]
[{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa', 'txt': '.ARPA'}]
[{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables', 'txt': 'IDN Practices Repository'}]
[{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/dnssec', 'txt': 'Root Key Signing Key'}]
[{'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains', 'txt': 'Domain Names'}, {'url': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/special', 'txt': 'Special Purpose Domains'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your second request, when you parse http://www.iana.org/domains and call `self.requests()` with `append=True` (because it's the default), this line:

```
request.meta['req_path'] = response.meta['req_path']
```

does *not copy* the list. Instead, it gets *a reference to the original list*. You then append (to the original list!) with the next line:

```
request.meta['req_path'].append(dict(txt=link.text, url=link.url))
```

On the next loop iteration, you again get a reference to the very same original list (that now already has two entries), and append to it again, and so forth.

What you want to do is create a new list for every request. You can do this for example by adding `.copy()` to the first line:

```
request.meta['req_path'] = response.meta['req_path'].copy()
```

or you could save a line by doing this:

```
request.meta['req_path'] = response.meta['req_path'] + [dict(txt=link.text, url=link.url)]
```